# How do I start a Unix-like job in Windows build on Appveyor?

Tags: python, windows, continuous-integration, appveyor

I have a separate dummy web server in my project that needs to be executed before running tests.

On any Linux environment (Travis, to be exact), I can start a command as a job with `&`. On Travis, I do below on `before_script`:

```
python tests/server.py &
```

However, Windows is a different environment and, from what I've seen on some resources, good-old `cmd` does not support a *job-like* functionality as in Linux system. I've seen some hackish solutions and tried those but no luck, I watched and stopped build on Appveyor by hand.

I also have tried some Powershell commands with no luck. What I've tried in `before_test`:

```
ps: 'Start-Process -NoNewWindow "python.exe tests/server.py"'
ps: 'Start-Process -NoNewWindow "${$ENV:PYTHON}\\python.exe tests/server.py"'
ps: 'Start-Process -NoNewWindow "${ENV:PYTHON}\\python.exe tests/server.py"'
ps: 'Start-Process -NoNewWindow "$env:PYTHON\\python.exe tests/server.py"'
ps: "Start-Process -NoNewWindow { $ENV:PYTHON\\python.exe tests/server.py }"
ps: "Start-Process -NoNewWindow { %PYTHON%\\python.exe tests/server.py }"  # this does not work since, apparently, ps does not support %-surrounded variables
```

I've tried these and either I have got something similar to `Unexpected token` or `File not found on specified path.` while Powershell did not even tell which file it could not find (was it [i] `PATH_TO_PYTHON/python.exe` or [ii] `tests/server.py` it was complaining about?).

> `Unexpected token` kind of error was not about `.appveyor.yml`. Build started successfully and `install` step was run.

How can I run a `before_test` command on AppVeyor and push it to background?